SignalR connection Error The underlying connection was closed before the hub handshake could complete
The error occurs when attempting to establish a SignalR connection. The connection is closed before the hub handshake can complete, causing the retry mechanism to trigger. This results in multiple retry attempts, but the connection is never successfully established.
I implemented a retry mechanism in the [chat_page.dart](vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mehem/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html) file to handle the connection failure. The [_retryConnection](vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/mehem/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html) method attempts to reconnect up to 5 times with a 5-second delay between attempts. I expected the connection to be re-established within these retries, but it continues to fail.
Here is the relevant code excerpt:
_retryConnection();
} else {
  Logger().i("Connection closed gracefully.");
}
setState(() {});

Future<void> _retryConnection() async {
  const int maxRetries = 5;
  int retryCount = 0;

  while (retryCount < maxRetries && !_isConnected) {
    try {
      Logger().i("Retrying SignalR connection: Attempt ${retryCount + 1}");
      await _hubConnection.start();
      _isConnected = true;
      Logger().i("SignalR reconnected successfully.");
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      Logger().e("Retry $retryCount failed: $e");
      retryCount++;
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    }
  }

  if (!_isConnected) {

Full Code :
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:legalis/api/api_service.dart';
import 'package:legalis/provider/chat/chat_detail_provider.dart';
import 'package:legalis/provider/communication/communication_provider.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/itransport.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/json_hub_protocol.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/signalr_client.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatPage({super.key, required this.id});

  final String? id;

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  late HubConnection _hubConnection;
  bool _isConnected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _initSignalR();
  }

  Future<void> _initSignalR() async {
    ApiService apiService = ApiService();
    JsonHubProtocol protocol = JsonHubProtocol();
    _hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          "https://legalis-api.webconsole.az/hubaction",
          options: HttpConnectionOptions(
            transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
            accessTokenFactory: () async {
              return await _getAccessToken(apiService) ?? '';
            },
            skipNegotiation: true,
            logger: null,
          ),
        )
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    // SignalR bağlantısını başlatmayı deneyin
    await _startConnection();
  }

  Future<String?> _getAccessToken(ApiService apiService) async {
    try {
      String? accessToken = await apiService.getAccessToken();
      Logger().i("Access Token: $accessToken");
      return accessToken;
    } catch (e) {
      Logger().d("Error fetching access token: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _startConnection() async {
    try {
      _hubConnection.onclose(({error}) => _onConnectionClose(error));
      _hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) {
        Logger().i("Received: $message");
      });

      await _hubConnection.start();
      _isConnected = true;
      Logger().i("SignalR connected.");
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      Logger().e("Error starting SignalR connection: $e");
      await _retryConnection();
    }
  }

  void _onConnectionClose(Exception? error) {
    _isConnected = false;
    if (error != null) {
      Logger().e("Connection closed with error: $error");
      _retryConnection();
    } else {
      Logger().i("Connection closed gracefully.");
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _retryConnection() async {
    const int maxRetries = 5;
    int retryCount = 0;

    while (retryCount < maxRetries && !_isConnected) {
      try {
        Logger().i("Retrying SignalR connection: Attempt ${retryCount + 1}");
        await _hubConnection.start();
        _isConnected = true;
        Logger().i("SignalR reconnected successfully.");
        break;
      } catch (e) {
        Logger().e("Retry $retryCount failed: $e");
        retryCount++;
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
      }
    }

    if (!_isConnected) {
      Logger().e("Failed to reconnect after $maxRetries attempts.");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _hubConnection.stop(); // Bağlantıyı kapatmayı unutmayın
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<String> refreshToken() async {
    final _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = ApiService();
    await apiService.init();
    var refreshToken = _prefs.getString('refresh_token');
    if (refreshToken != null) {
      try {
        final response = await apiService.dio.post(
          'Auth/refresh-token-login',
          data: {'refreshToken': refreshToken},
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final newAccessToken = response.data['access_token'];
          _prefs.setString('access_token', newAccessToken);
          _prefs.setString('refresh_token', response.data['refresh_token']);
          return newAccessToken;
        } else {
          throw Exception('Failed to refresh token: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        Logger().e("Error refreshing token: $e");
        throw e;
      }
    }
    throw Exception('Refresh token is null');
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String message, {required String receiverId}) async {
    if (_isConnected) {
      await _hubConnection.invoke("SendMessage",
          args: [message, receiverId]).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        Logger().e("Error sending message: $error");
      });
    } else {
      Logger().e("Cannot send message: Not connected to the server.");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000E2B),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leadingWidth: 0,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF000E2B),
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 14,
              height: 14,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF34A853),
                shape: OvalBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            const Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Text(
                  'Məhəmməd Məhəmməd Məhəmməd Məhəmməd Məhəmməd Məhəmməd Vekil',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    letterSpacing: 0.38,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              context.pushNamed('callpage', queryParameters: {'id': '1'});
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 46,
              height: 46,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/call_user.svg'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Consumer<ChatDetailProvider>(
                        builder: (context, provider, child) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 20,
                            ),
                            reverse: true,
                            itemCount: provider.chatList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              bool isSameUser = index > 0 &&
                                  provider.chatList[index].isMe ==
                                      provider.chatList[index - 1].isMe;
                              return Align(
                                alignment: provider.chatList[index].isMe
                                    ? Alignment.centerRight
                                    : Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 12,
                                        left: 10,
                                        bottom: provider.chatList[index].isMe
                                            ? 13
                                            : 13,
                                        right: 7,
                                      ),
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        bottom: isSameUser ? 5 : 10,
                                        top: isSameUser ? 5 : 10,
                                      ),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.6,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: provider.chatList[index].isMe
                                            ? const Color.fromRGBO(3, 44, 96, 1)
                                            : const Color(0xFF3467E4),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(20),
                                          topRight: const Radius.circular(20),
                                          bottomRight:
                                              provider.chatList[index].isMe
                                                  ? Radius.zero
                                                  : const Radius.circular(20),
                                          bottomLeft:
                                              provider.chatList[index].isMe
                                                  ? const Radius.circular(20)
                                                  : Radius.zero,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                        provider.chatList[index].txt,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Consumer<CommunicationProvider>(
                        builder: (context, provider, child) {
                          return provider.isConnected
                              ? Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 16),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(right: 11),
                                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                            minHeight: 52,
                                            maxHeight: 100,
                                          ),
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller: _controller,
                                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                                            maxLines: 3,
                                            minLines: 1,
                                            keyboardType:
                                                TextInputType.multiline,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            ),
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              hintText:
                                                  '${AppLocalizations.of(context)?.enterMessage}...',
                                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Color(0xFFABB0BC),
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              ),
                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                              ),
                                              filled: true,
                                              fillColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  51, 62, 85, 1),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                            Provider.of<ChatDetailProvider>(
                                                    context,
                                                    listen: false)
                                                .sendMessage(_controller.text,
                                                    receiverId:
                                                        widget.id ?? '');
                                            _controller.clear();
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: 52,
                                          height: 52,
                                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                            'assets/icons/send_icon.svg',
                                            width: 52,
                                            height: 52,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: 44,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 16),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFF6A6A6A),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Bu söhbət artıq yekunlaşıb.',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Hi Mahammad Azimzada, please set skipNegotiation = false and let signalr self-select the protocol, if the websocket is not available, we will look at whether long polling can be connected successfully.

And we also need to enable asp.net core signalr logging feature to check server side logs. One more thing, have you used azure signalr ?

Hello Json Pan
"skipNegotiation = false" I tried this feature in every way but it didn't work, the problem is not caused by this.
On the Asp.Net side, when I delete the "Authorize" Attribute, this problem does not occur.
It was published in "DigitalOcean"-not with "Azure SignalR" backend
